# Looking for a search function across multiple columns in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm looking to do have a user search field on my page to allow me to select based on finding results across several columns of data.

Something like this.

sample data

| Model | Color | Make |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hilux | Blue | Toyota |
| Rav4 | Grey | Toyota |
| Suberb | Red | Skoda |

I want a search field where users could enter a search for "blue toyota" or "red suberb".
I have created a calc column and joined all the fields together but the only searches that work are single value searches such as "Grey", "Rav4".

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to achieve this is to create a custom column in Power Query
[custom column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dv1rA.png)

And add a text filter in the front end, set it to advanced filtering and select contains function
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irt23.png)

Or explore the third party visuals to get a slicer that filter like contains function above

Comment: This does not let a user enter the searches they want - It does let me set a complex predefined search but that's not what I was looking for. I'll try to be more clear in future.

Comment: Also trying to do this...@RonSnoek, any luck?